# VBA dynamic array of comboboxes and textboxes click event

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, vb6

Hey all I have the following VBA code that allows me to have a click event on a dynamically created comboboxes and textboxes onto the userform.

userform:

```
Option Explicit

Dim comboboxBoxColct As New Collection
Dim textboxBoxColct As New Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Dim comboboxEvent As Class1
Dim textboxEvent As Class1

   '..lots more code within here

   If LCase(TypeName(controller(i))) = "combobox" Then
      Set comboboxEvent = New Class1
      Set comboboxEvent.comboboxBox = controller(i)
      comboboxBoxColct.Add comboboxEvent
   ElseIf LCase(TypeName(controller(i))) = "textbox" Then
      Set textboxEvent = New Class1
      Set textboxEvent.textboxBox = controller(i)
      textboxBoxColct.Add textboxEvent
   End If
End Sub
```

Class1:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents comboboxBox As MSForms.ComboBox
Public WithEvents textboxBox As MSForms.TextBox

Private Sub comboboxBox_Click()
    MsgBox "worked"
End Sub

Private Sub textboxBox_Click()
    MsgBox "worked"
End Sub
```

[image]

The above code **works just fine** when using it for the **comboboxes**. However, once I get to a **textbox within that array** it never does the msgbox popup.

I am guessing it may have to do with the array number for that box as it may be looking for a **0** instead of whatever the number is in the array **6** so its starting at **6** instead of **0** since its the first textbox in the array it sees.

What can I do in order to get them both to work within the same array?

Comment: `textboxBox`, really? ;-) FWIW I'd use `If TypeOf controller(i) Is MSForms.TextBox` instead of the stringly-typed `TypeName` check. I think we might need to see how the `controller` array is populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum... seems that a textbox in VBA does not have a `Click` event, so when I changed it to handle the `Change` (no pun intended) event instead, it shows the popup if I type a letter into the textbox.

```
Private Sub textboxBox_Change() 'was textboxBox_Click()
    MsgBox "worked"
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah crap, I wanted to say that and then moved to another tab and forgot!

Comment: Depending on the changes you are using, it is better to use `TextBox_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)`. e.g.: when the user needs to type something on textbox and the text is changed, so he can't write the full text and the text is changed